# webservice rest para receber um xml em delphi

Tags: delphi, web-service, delphi-10

Boa tarde.
Um cliente quer me envie um arquivo .xml 
Criei um projeto DataSnap Rest Application.
Fiz a implementação do metodo da seguinte forma para JSON

```
function TFo_SM_Fornecedor.updateFornecedor(TObjJson: TJsonObject): TJsonValue;
Var
  Fornecedor: TFornecedor;
begin
  Fornecedor := TJson.JsonToObject<TFornecedor>(TObjJson.toJson);
  Try
    Result := TJSONString.Create('Incluindo Cliente..: ' +
      Fornecedor.tx_razaosocial);
  Finally
    FreeandNil(Fornecedor);
  End;    
end;
```

Para receber um tipo TJsonObject funciona perfeitamente.
Mas como falei no inicio irei receber um .xml.
Já fiz vários códigos em delphi para receber um xml e colocar os valores na base, mas é a primeira vez que tenho que desenvolver um servidor e estou sem uma direçõo.
Algum dos colegas pode me dar uma luz?
A principio ( já a alguns dias) estou tentando mudar o parâmetro da linha

> function TFo_SM_Fornecedor.updateFornecedor(TObjJson: TJsonObject):

para algo do tipo

> function TFo_SM_Fornecedor.updateFornecedor(pArquivo_XML:
>   TStringTream):

Mas estou sem sucesso.
Se algum dos senhores puder me fornecer uma luz agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Não acho que precise alterar o parâmetro, você poderia receber o xml como uma String sem problemas, bastaria apenas identificar um campo específico do json...

Penso em algo enviado para você como:

```
[
  {
    "xml": "todo xml aqui"
  }
]
```

Sua função receberia um json simples e testaria se a chave for "xml" trate como xml, se não continue fazendo o que já faz...

Isto eu tenho implementado e funciona perfeitamente para vários formatos de arquivos e minha API.

Para me enviar uma imagem eu solicito que seja uma String, ou seja um base64, para me enviar um MP3 me envie uma String, o solicitante converte em  `TStringTream` e me envia os bytes em String.

Do meu lado apenas reconheço a chave.

Comment: Bom dia @Júnior Moreira. Obrigado pela sua atenção :). Cara.. o CLIENTE não ira MUDAR O .XML  dele.  Isso é fato. Então tenho que receber do jeito que vem. O sistema dele envia um arquivo .XML para um endereço. A única coisa que ele consegue fazer do lado dele é MUDAR O ENDEREÇO para onde vai o .XML.  Me Compreende? Por isso eu acho que tenho que mudar o parametro da função.  Caso seja possível nos falarmos por skype, seria de grande ajuda para mim. :) Ou por aqui mesmo :) Abraços..

Comment: Ok, vou preparar uma resposta adequada ja que o cliente não pode mudar a requisição!

Comment: Bom dia @Júnior Moreira. Obrigado pela atenção.. :) Fico no aguardo.. Estou tentando por aqui algo também. Espero chegar a algum lugar. Abraços.